# Xcode won't detect device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, deployment

I'm having a bit of an issue testing my app using my iPhone. Last week I upgraded to Xcode 4.3. I was able to test my apps on my iPhone (which was running iOS 4.3). Today I upgraded my iPhone to iOS 5.1 and now Xcode wont detect my iPhone (btw SDK is 5.1).

I'm not too sure what to do, I've even tried changing the Deployment target in Xcode back down to 4.3, but still nothing.

Comment: Tried restarting Xcode, restarting the mac?

Comment: Yes i've tried restarting xcode, the mac and the phone

Comment: Just to be clear, your using Xcode 4.3.2 right?

Comment: Thats correct, I'm running xcode 4.3.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure the device is "Enabled for development" under Organizer in Xcode. I've seen cases, where Xcode doesn't recognise the device, because it wasn't setup to be a development device.

Comment: After I installed iOS Beta (7.1) on my iPhone, XCode doesn't works and  tell me that I need to restore my iPhone.

Comment: With the betas you need to use the Xcode Developer Preview versions. As only they have the beta SDK and are able to see the development device.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem but my device **was already enabled for development**. Here are the steps I took to get it working.

If you want to cheat, try the last step. That's what got it working for me!

1. Try restarting both Xcode and the device. Separately.
2. Make sure you're using the latest iOS SDK under Base SDK (in Targets / Projects > Build Settings) and that it's a greater version that what's running on your device
3. Check Project > Build Settings > iOS Deployment Target is **less or equal** to what's on your device.

It turned out, when I'd created a new project, it had chosen an iOS Deployment Target **greater** than my device version.